# Tefillin in view of toilet

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot

According to many, it is not permissible to say a *beracha* or read Torah when in view of a toilet, even if that toilet is in a different room (see SA OC 83).

I want to know if according to any is there a similar halacha with regards to wearing tefillin, given that one is also not generally allowed to enter a bathroom with Tefillin exposed (ibid 43).

Comment: From the language of SA OC 43:5 I understand there is no restriction to wearing tefilin more than 4 amot from a bathroom. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: @mbloch I am asking, if the door is open and one can see through it to the inside and can directly see the toilet